# php code to display null on textbox changed event

Tags: javascript, php

Below i placed my complete code..

I am populating values in another textbox on keydown event of textbox..

Every thing is working fine...

**But My question is how to return 0 in all textboxes  which populates from key down event...if keydown event is null.**

**Bcoz when i try to edit some value to null then another textbox values remain as it is...**

customerdata.php page code

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');
$q = $_GET['q'];
$city = $database->getRows("SELECT HM.id AS hawkerid,HM.mobile As hawkermobile,CM.id AS subagentid,CM.tehsil AS Centername,CM.subagentname As subagentname FROM hawker_master HM inner join sub_agent_master CM on CM.id = HM.subagentname WHERE hawker_name = :hawker_name", array(':hawker_name'=>"$q"));  
$info = array();
foreach($city as $row)
{
    $cID = $row['id'];
    $cName = $row['subagentname'];      
    $hawid = $row['hawkerid'];  
    $subid = $row['subagentid'];    

    $info[] = array('name' => $cName,'hid' => $hawid,'sid' => $subid);
}
echo json_encode($info);
?>
```

Below is my javascript

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function show(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementByName("hawkername").value="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) 
        {         
          document.getElementById("subagentname").value = data[i].name;
          document.getElementById("hawkernum").value = data[i].hid; 
          document.getElementById("subagentnum").value = data[i].sid;    
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","customerdata.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

My textbox display code

```
<input id="hawker_name" onKeyDown="show(this.value)" value="<?php echo $data['hawker'];?>"  />
<input  type="" id="hawkernum" value="<?php echo $data['hawkerid'];?>"  name="hawkername" />
```

Comment: `if keydown event is null` - what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getElementById` for id `hawkernum` Change this portion in `Javascript`.

```
if (!str || str.trim().length <= 0)
{
    document.getElementById("hawkernum").value="";
    return;
}
```

And declare input type for

```
<input  type="text" id="hawkernum" value="<?php echo $data['hawkerid'];?>"  name="hawkername" />
```